# Resizing and aliasing in computer science

Tags: terminology, image-processing, graphics

If you resize an 1000x1000 raster image to 10x10 and resize it back to 1000x1000 is this considered to be an example of [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing)?

Comment: Never heard of 'aliasing' to express the suggested meaning. 'Aliasing' in cs captures the notion of 'indirection' and multiple access paths to the same entity. The most Notable example probably are references to the Same Memory Location through Pointers and variables in Programming languages like C.

Comment: @collapsar Aliasing and anti-aliasing in the computer graphics definition, not in pointers and variables. This is more about sampling: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing

Comment: sure it is, but the result of your transformation will most certainly be very distinguishable from the original and the process will thus not fall under the definition of aliasing. You might of course regard the Resolution Reduction as a Kind of sampling which maps different originals to the same representation. The Term 'aliasing' might apply then though i still feel its use would be unusual without express context.

Comment: What does the picture have to do with the question?

Comment: @DavidRicherby illustrates aliasing in signal processing

Comment: think yes it could be regarded as aliasing because the resize operation can be seen as basically a sampling operation. also an "artifact"

Answer (score 1):

When you resize to a lower resolution, there are several ways to do
it. If you average values of the pixels that merge into a single one,
you simply have a loss of resolution, which amounts to keeping only
the lower spatial frequencies (counting frequencies relative to image
size, not to pixel size).  However, if you reduce resoution by
sampling, i.e. replacing a bunch of pixels by the value of one of
them, you may overplay high frequencies, not meaningful at the given sampling (spatial) frequency, leading to all kinds of
artefacts such as moiré effects for images.

When you recreate the image at former resolution, you cannot in
principle recreate
lost information. But you try to make educated guess as to the effect
most likely to occur or not to occur in most images. Hence, you apply
some reprocessing to the image so as to eliminate unlikely phenomena,
or play down phenomena that you know could not have survived the initial size
reduction (they may or may not have been there, but you know that
later presence is not due to original existence).

Typically, as you know that the image reduction has necessarily lost
some higher spatial frequencies, or distorted their role, you can
choose to eliminate or play doen those frequencies at the recreated higher
resolution, as they do not originate from the initial image.

For example, if you had a large geometric image, reduction and back
resizing will produce a staircase effect on most straight lines. These
abrupt changes correspond to high spatial bandwith. By removing these high
frequencies, you will recreate shaded areas that smooth down the staircase effect on the
straight lines.

Aliasing has to do with the artefact due to the combined effect of
sampling and reproducing back a sampled observation of a theoretically
continuous phenomenon (or considered as such because its initial resolution is
significantly greater than the sampling rate), may be an image, a
sound, a film,etc. As seen above, the sampling technique does matter.
Antialiasing consist of the techniques used to eliminate
artefacts known as likely to occur.  It cannot recreate lost
information unless you knew separately that the processed information
has to satisfy some constraints, which antialiasing can then use to
improve the image. For example, you may know that geometric images use
straight lines more often than small staircases.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing) has more technical information.

Comment: So, is that a yes?

Comment: It is not quite a yes. Aliasing denotes rather the effects of the procedure you describe, which are usually undesirable effects. That is what I am summarizing in the last paragraph of the answer.  Wheels turning backward in a film is an aliasing effect (often called stroboscopic in the case of motion).

Comment: If the original image is such that the procedure you suggest does not change it at all, there is no aliasing. This may be the case for very coarse grained images.